# Hover over image and make link appear when in a javascript gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im using a javascript gallery for four or five images,what im wanting is for a link to appear over the image when hovered over, ive seen other people ask this but nothing works for me, could someone link a js fiddle so i can understand?

I know the jquery is something along these lines

```
jQ: 
   $(function(){
            $('.ih').hover(
              // Over
            function(){
                var $ih = $(this);
                $ih.find('.ih-info').stop(true,true).animate({opacity:0.8}, 400);
            },
            // Out
            function(){
                var $ih = $(this);
                $ih.find('.ih-info').stop(true,true).animate({opacity:0}, 400);
            }
        ).find('.ih-info').css('opacity',0);
    });
```

Here is my html;

```
 <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                    <li>
                        <div 
                            <img src="images/fleet_vehciles/sf56omm_high_volume_jetvac.jpg"/>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <img src="images/fleet_vehciles/sc62lco_low_volume_jetvac_rioned.jpg"/></a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <img src="images/fleet_vehciles/sa08ff0_support_van.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <img src="images/fleet_vehciles/mx58lxc_cctv_van.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Please help as ive been at this for ages and im going insane... thanks for any help!

Comment: what is `ih-info` element?

Comment: it would be the div that fades in when hovered over the image?

Comment: @CalvinTaylor, see this jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/vogao3y0/2/  you need to update your code and save the link and share it with other. Note - you have closed `</a>` tags after `<img>` tag, remove it

Comment: Why do you need this part `.find('.ih-info').css('opacity',0);` at the end of your function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need javascript to accomplish this, you can do it all through css using the `hover` pseudo class.

I've included the code here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGpeq

HTML:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li>

        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100"/>
        <a href="#">link</a>

    </li>

    <li>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100"/>
        <a href="#">link</a>
    </li>

     <li>
         <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" />
         <a href="#">link</a>
     </li>

     <li>
         <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" />
          <a href="#">link</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
ul li {
  position: relative;
}

ul li a {
  position: absolute;
  left:0; top:0;
}

a {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

ul li:hover a {
  opacity: 1;
}
```